# Swing JComboBox get previous item when new item selected

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm a beginner in swing
I have the following code :

```
String[] names = new String[]{
            "James", "Joshua", "Matt", "John", "Paul" };

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(names);
    // Create an ActionListener for the JComboBox component.
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // Get the source of the component, which is our combo
            // box.
            JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

            // Print the selected items and the action command.
            Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("Selected Item  = " + selected);

        }
    });
```

Suppose the object that is selected is Paul and I select after John. So here actionPerfomed is triggered and the `comboBox.getSelectedItem();` will return us `John`. My question is there any way to intercept `Paul` before ?

Comment: Well, you could use a `ItemListener`, which, from memory, will tell you the "from" and 'to" events or you could just keep a reference to the last selected value :/

Comment: and how I can implement it ?

Comment: Well, you might start with [How to Write an Item Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) and I think [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) has some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `addItemListener` to check if any item has been selected

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    String selected = (String) event.getItem();
                    // add your logic
                }
            }
        });
```

Resource: [JComboBoxComponent](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningforChangestotheSelectedIteminaJComboBoxComponent.htm)

Comment: Just beware, this will likely be called twice, once for the deselection and once for the selection - so you might want to inspect the type of even before making decisions about what should be done ... and since that's the basic question the OP is asking, you might consider demonstrating it ;)

Comment: I think the OP wants the previous item that was selected, so you should be using `ItemEvent.DESELECTED` otherwise you can just use the ActionLIstener as in the example because that gives you the current selection.